# Script for "Split text to columns" with form in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, ifttt

I am using IFTTT to push forms sent to my email address to a Google Sheet. The contents get pasted into column A in one big clump, and I can't figure out how to split the text into columns in a way that formats well. Ideally, I'd like to only include the answers to questions on the form in the columns to the right of column A.

Here is a sample of what gets pasted into column A:

```
New customer message on May  9, 2017 at 12:15 PM

You received a new message from your Online Store's contact form.

Name:

Jon Snow

Email:

sample@gmail.com

Q1:

Yes

Q2:

No

Q3:

yes

Q4:

no

Q5:

no
```

Is there some sort of script I could use to display the name, email address, and answers to the 5 questions in the 7 columns to the right of column A?

Answer (score 0):

I have a rudimentary solution that you can build on if you like.

My solution **assumes a few things**, firstly the **name is always going to be two words**, secondly the **answers are always going to be yes or no**.

This will work for any number of rows in column A.

The whole solution is based on splitting up the string in a particular way, and it's not very fluid as it assumes the amount of spaces and the formatting will always be the same.  It's a start :)

```
    function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRangelength = ss.getDataRange().getLastRow();  
  var strRef = ss.getRange("A1:A" + dataRangelength);
  var str = strRef.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < dataRangelength; i++) {
    var row = str[i];
    var A1ref = i + 1
    var rowRef = ss.getRange("A" + A1ref);
    if (row != "") {

  var arr = row.toString().split(" ");
  var arr1 = arr[20].toString().split("\n");
  var arr2 = arr[21].toString().split("\n");

   rowRef.offset(0, 1).setValue(arr1[4] + " " + arr2[0]);
   rowRef.offset(0, 2).setValue(arr2[4]);
   rowRef.offset(0, 3).setValue(arr2[8]);
   rowRef.offset(0, 4).setValue(arr2[12]);
   rowRef.offset(0, 5).setValue(arr2[16]);
   rowRef.offset(0, 6).setValue(arr2[20]);
   rowRef.offset(0, 7).setValue(arr2[24]);
    }}
}
```